# Updating a node within a KML file using Golang

Tags: go

I'm working with a KML file which I'm using to plot a LineString within Google Earth. I'm receiving GPS data from a USB adapter and feeding the coordinates to a Go channel. I'm attempting to read off the channel and update a node within the KML file to add to the LineString (thus plotting my movements).

Here is the KML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Folder>
    <name>Foo</name>
    <open>1</open>
    <Document>
        <name>Bar</name>
        <Placemark>
            <Style>
                <LineStyle>
                    <color>ff00ff00</color>
                    <width>5</width>
                </LineStyle>
                <PolyStyle>
                    <color>ff4080ff</color>
                    <fill>1</fill>
                    <outline>1</outline>
                </PolyStyle>
            </Style>
            <LineString>
                <tessellate>1</tessellate>
                <coordinates>
                    1.23411166666667,10.12345678901234,0 
                    1.23421166666667,10.12345678901234,0 
                    1.23431166666667,10.12345678901234,0 
                    1.23431166666667,10.32345678901234,0 
                </coordinates>
            </LineString>
        </Placemark>
    </Document>
</Folder>
</kml>
```

I'm looking to append to the coordinates node.

I was thinking one of two approaches. Firstly parse the file and using Regex look for `</coordinates>` and insert the data before it. Secondly, parse the XML and look to update the value in the node. The latter seems the more sensible option, but everything I've Googled shows me how to add a new node to an XML tree, as opposed to append to an existing entry.

What I've attempted so far feels like a real mess, inefficiently opens the file on every read from the channel, and ultimately doesn't work.

```
type LineString struct {
    coordinates string `xml:"coordinates"`
}    

func plotLocation(c chan data.GpsPos) {
    /*
        continuously read from the channel
        use the location data to plot a breadcrumb trail
    */

    defer wg.Done()

    for currentCoords := range c {

        file, err := os.Open("/Users/me/foo.kml")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        defer file.Close()

        var buf bytes.Buffer
        decoder := xml.NewDecoder(file)
        encoder := xml.NewEncoder(&buf)

        for {
            token, err := decoder.Token()
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("error getting token: %v\n", err)
                break
            }
            switch v := token.(type) {
            case xml.StartElement:
                if v.Name.Local == "LineString" {

                    var coords LineString
                    if err = decoder.DecodeElement(&coords, &v); err != nil {
                        log.Fatal(err)
                    }
                    coords.coordinates += fmt.Sprintf("%f,%f,%d\n", currentCoords.Lat, currentCoords.Long, 0)
                    if err = encoder.EncodeElement(coords, v); err != nil {
                        log.Fatal(err)
                    }
                    continue
                }
            }
            if err := encoder.EncodeToken(xml.CopyToken(token)); err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong and also is there a better approach to writing this data to the file (which will occur once every second or so)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the file change outside of your application? If not, then you could parse the file once before the loop, maintain a list of coordinates, and write it out each time it changes so external applications can see the intermediate results.  This will also be useful if you plan to do any more transformations, or if you want to generate the whole file from scratch at the beginning.

---

First, you will want a struct with the appropriate tags (see [xml.Unmarshal](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal)).  I usually start with an online generator for these sorts of things:

```golang
// type definition adapted from https://www.onlinetool.io/xmltogo/

type KML struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"kml"`
    Text    string   `xml:",chardata"`
    XMLNS   string   `xml:"xmlns,attr"`
    GX      string   `xml:"gx,attr"`
    KML     string   `xml:"kml,attr"`
    Atom    string   `xml:"atom,attr"`
    Folder  struct {
        Text     string `xml:",chardata"`
        Name     string `xml:"name"`
        Open     string `xml:"open"`
        Document struct {
            Text      string `xml:",chardata"`
            Name      string `xml:"name"`
            Placemark struct {
                Text  string `xml:",chardata"`
                Style struct {
                    Text      string `xml:",chardata"`
                    LineStyle struct {
                        Text  string `xml:",chardata"`
                        Color string `xml:"color"`
                        Width string `xml:"width"`
                    } `xml:"LineStyle"`
                    PolyStyle struct {
                        Text    string `xml:",chardata"`
                        Color   string `xml:"color"`
                        Fill    string `xml:"fill"`
                        Outline string `xml:"outline"`
                    } `xml:"PolyStyle"`
                } `xml:"Style"`
                LineString struct {
                    Text        string `xml:",chardata"`
                    Tessellate  string `xml:"tessellate"`
                    Coordinates string `xml:"coordinates"`
                } `xml:"LineString"`
            } `xml:"Placemark"`
        } `xml:"Document"`
    } `xml:"Folder"`
}
```

I would make some helpers for this:

```golang
func readKML(filename string) (*KML, error) {
  f, err := os.Open(filename)
  if err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("opening KML file: %w", err) // contains filename
  }
  defer f.Close() // reading, ignoring error is acceptable
  var kml KML
  if err := xml.NewDecoder(f).Decode(&kml); err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("decoding XML from %q as KML: %w", filename, err)
  }
  return &kml, nil
}

func writeKML(filename string, kml *KML) error {
  f, err := os.Create(filename)
  if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("creating KML file: %w", err) // contains filename
  }
  defer f.Close() // double close is OK for *os.File
  enc := xml.NewEncoder(f)
  enc.Indent("", "    ")
  if err := enc.Encode(kml); err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("encoding KML to %q: %w", filename, err)
  }
  return nil
}
```

And then your loop can look something like this:

```golang
kml, err := readKML(filename)
if err != nil {
  return err // contains context
}

coordinates := strings.Fields(kml.Folder.Document.Placemark.LineString.Coordinates)

for coord := range incoming {
  line := fmt.Sprintf("%f,%f,%d\n", coord.Lat, coord.Long, 0)
  coordinates = append(coordinates, coord)
  
  kml.Folder.Document.Placemark.LineString.Coordinates = strings.Join(coordinates, "\n")
  if err := writeKML(filename, kml); err != nil {
    log.Printf("Warning: failed to update %q: %s", filename, err)
  }
}
```

---

When looking at the code you have, I suspect that the issue is that you are deferring your file close, which will execute when the function returns, not when the loop continues.  You may be able to make this approach work as well, and to do so I would recommend breaking your logic into functions so that each piece can be tested independently, which also will likely mean that your defer is now scoped properly within a function.